# Any problems in saying `good to know (about) that`?

Tags: adverbs, cleft-constructions

Are there any problems in saying the following when responding to one answer in the comment?

> good to know (about) that?

How do I refine that?

> well to know that?
>
> nice to know that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (It's/That's) good to know that

is both grammatical and colloquial. It's an ordinary cleft construction, representing

> To know that is good

in which *to know that* is an infinitive verb phrase acting as a noun, the subject. The sentence naturally takes an adjective as the predicative complement, and you may use any other adjective which the situation calls for:

> It's nice to know that. / That's nice to know. / To know that is nice.
>   It's convenient to know that. / That's convenient to know. / To know that is convenient.
>   It's discouraging to know that. / That's discouraging  to know. / To know that is discouraging.

But adverbs are right out:

> <sup>✲</sup>It's nicely to know that. / <sup>✲</sup>That's nicely to know. / <sup>✲</sup>To know that is nicely.
>   <sup>✲</sup>It's discouragingly to know that. / <sup>✲</sup>That's discouragingly to know. / <sup>✲</sup>To know that is discouragingly.
>   <sup>✲</sup>It's conveniently to know that. / <sup>✲</sup>That's conveniently to know. / <sup>✲</sup>To know that is conveniently.

*Well* is a special case. Until about three hundred years ago the use of *well* as an adjective was common, and it still lingers in such fossilized phrases as "It is just as well (that)" or "all will be well". Outside those phrases, however, it is obsolete, or at least literary. It's unlikely you'd hear anybody today say

> <sup>?</sup>It's well to know that. / <sup>?</sup>That's well to know. / <sup>?</sup>To know that is well.

---

<sup>✲</sup> *marks a usage as unacceptable*
<sup>?</sup> *marks a usage as only marginally acceptable*

Answer (score 0):

It's more common to say "That's good to know."  Or, more simply: "Good to know."

Answer (score 0):

"It is good" would have been the sort of thing that Victorian teachers would correct in their students to "it is well", on the grounds that is is a verb and well is the adverbial form of good.  This is still correct--if perhaps a little stuffy--English usage, but street English (especially in America) often substitutes good for well.

```
Lord Crustwick: How do you do?
Lord Sandwich: Very well, thank you.  Pleased to meet you.
Abe Lincoln: Good thanks, glad to know you.
```